# Centralized logging for JBoss / log4j?

Tags: logging, jboss

Does anyone have advice or a pointer to articles on how to centralize logs in JBoss?

JBoss will log to syslog, which makes it easy, but doing so breaks multi line debug messages (and Jboss loves dropping exception stack traces in the logs).  I can rsync the logs, but that isn't realtime.

Log4j has appenders for TCP and multicast sockets, so it seems like something probably exists for streaming logs, but I haven't found a receiver for the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want log4j's [SocketAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html) / [SocketReceiver](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/receivers/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketReceiver.html) functionality.

Comment: That is the solution I eventually went with.  The log4j distribution has a SocketServer appliation that can be run to catch logs sent from the SocketAppender.  Work of caution, if Jboss can't write logs it stop processing requests.  VERY BAD.  Avoid using the TCP SocketAppender since a network break will cause JBoss to lockup.  The UDP or Multicast appenders are a better choice.